# Security concerns in using passkey (WebAuthn) to encrypt data

Tags: webauthn

I have a web application that runs on the client side only (no backend server), and I need a way to encrypt user data on the blockchain.  Users who encrypted the data needs to be able to decrypt the data later.

I'm thinking of using the WebAuth API to generate a passkey and use the sha256 hash of the public key from the passkey to encrypt the data.  I don't store this public key anywhere. When I want to decrypt the data, I use WebAuth to get a signature from the passkey and recover the public key from the signature.

In order to recover the public key, I only use P256 elliptic curve to generate the passkey.

Is there any security concern with this design? For example, other than the website that owns the domain, can the passkey signature be retrieved any other way?

Comment: Welcome to the community. When you put everything on the client's side you put the ability to intercept, modify or manipulation the passkey to the user as well in my opinion.

Comment: @SirMuffington thank you for your comment. Could you please elaborate how my design open up the ability to intercept, modify or manipulate the passkey but not in the original design of the `webAuthn` design? 

The only thing I deviate from the `webAuthn` design was to `NOT` store the public key we get when initially creating the passkey.  Not storing the public key in a centralized backend database means that I have to manually recover it when I need to use it to decrypt the data. That's why I'm limiting to only using the P256 curve which allows public key recovery from the signature.

Comment: It's well explained in the answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your approach contradicts sound cryptographic design principles.  In cryptography, we assume that certain things (primarily secret keys) are secret, and everything else is public, and the design of the cryptosystem is secure in that context.

You've taken an item which is explicitly public, the public key, and made it into a secret key, which isn't secure.  Typically, WebAuthn keys are unique per site, but a design which used a single key pair for all sites would still be cryptographically secure according to the WebAuthn design (although it would be very bad for privacy), in which case your approach would be trivially insecure.  It may be that *practically* it is very unlikely that other parties have access to the public key, but by relying on that you rely on assumptions beyond the design of the passkey and risk practically exploitable vulnerabilities.

Comment: Thank you and well said. It's insecure to rely on something that's designed to be public, even though it's not publicly accessible today.